# How to move without VR or AR device?

Tags: mrtk

Most if not all MR devices drive the camera automatically. How is this supposed to be achieved using Windows Standalone for example, where I use the mouse as input device. I suppose there is some sort of WASD movement, either already available, or implementable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Input Simulation Service](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/InputSimulation/InputSimulationService.html) to move the camera in Windows Standalone. Then the camera will move using WASD. To enable this for Windows Standalone, just enable the Input Simulation Service for the Windows Standalone Platform:

[image]

Comment: Just a mention. The InputSimulationService is not available in a standalone build. This issue mentions this: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3971. I failed myself that's why I know :)